# mongodb refuses to accept further connections because there are too many connections

Tags: mongodb

I developed a java web application that (when a certain button is pressed) reads data into a mongodb database and (when another particular button is pressed) reads data from the database.

However, now the database refuses to accept further connections because there are too many connections:

[image]

When I go to the mongodb-shell and type in the command

```
 db.currentOp()
```

I am told that there is only one in-progress operation for the database instance:

[image]

However, when I run the command

```
db.currentOp(true)
```

to also include operations on idle connections and system operations, I get a long list of operations. ... Here's a short excerpt:

[image]

What are all these connections doing? Why and how were they created? Can I just delete them all? (How would I do that?)

Comment: What OS are you running MongoDB? Does the Webapp and `mongod` run on the same machine?

Comment: Can we not establish that as of your previous question ["Creating only ONE connection to the database in web app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118989/creating-only-one-connection-to-the-database-in-web-app) you are in fact incorrectly creating "bucketloads" more instances of client connections than you actually need. This is in fact exactly what happens when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be saving the data from client side. 
You must send data to web app and save data in MongoDB from there.

Or

You might not be closing the connections in web app after opening them. You must close connections otherwise, it can lead to memory leaks.

For deleting the connections, You just have to restart the MongoDb service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .... At first I indeed did not close a database connection after opening it , however I have changed that. Now, after every read or write operation on the db, I close the database instance I created. I tried killing the connections with control-c ... this stopped the database but when I restarted it, the number of connections was again too high for the database to accept a connection. 
... I'm not sure what you mean with "You might be saving the data from client side." (Why would that be a problem?) ... In fact, the data come from a web-service

Comment: You didn't mention any code. So I thought you mistakenly wrote saving code in client side. And since, you are testing locally, it didn't show any error.

Comment: ok, I understand ... Why does restarting the mongoldb server not kill the connections?

Comment: What are these connections for anyway? except for one, they are all idle connections and system operations? But what are idle connections? how can I recognise whether a connection is idle or a system operation?

Comment: Now I can't even start the mongoldb server anymore ... it's at once "shutting down with code:100"

Comment: Every connection is ever created by your code. But was left open. The mongo keeps track of them for debugging and security reasons. 

And if restart is not working, they might be cleared automatically after some time, as I can you must have run app more times then number of connections you pasted here.

Also don't try that clearing of connections after a hour, it relies on restart and it is not safe to use as mentioned in later comment.

Comment: Try restarting device followed by these,

On windows, check for C:/data/db folder
on linux, use sudo mongod

Comment: still can't start the server ... same message as before

Comment: what about this?https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/
the problem is: how can I know which of the operation are system processes?

Comment: Utter nonsense. The MongoDB java driver maintains a connection pool. The size of said pool and your available number of file descriptors available to the euid  of MongoDB seem to mismatch. And DONT EVER use sudo without a user parameter to run mongodb. This makes the process run with euid 0 aka `root` - a security nightmare, and aside from that it changes ownership of files necessary to run mongod to `root`.

Comment: @Markus: thank you for your comment ... what is utter nonsense? (if you mean the link I provided in my last comment, this is from the official docs for mongodb - or do you mean something else?)

Comment: @steady_progress Please answer my questions in comments to your original question, so we get the problem solved. And by utter nonsense I referred to.the assumptions and solutions in this answer.